# Calculating a variance of a division of two sums.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation, variance

I have got the following model:
$$Y_i=\beta X_i+\epsilon_i, \hspace{1cm} i=1,...,n$$
where $X_i$ are independent $N(\mu, \tau^2)$ random variables and $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d. $N(0, \sigma^2)$.

I need to calculate variance of $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}$$
As: 
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}=\beta+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}$$
I went as follows:
$$Var\bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}\bigg)=\frac{E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i)^2]}{E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]}-\frac{E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i]^2}{E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i]^2}=\frac{E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i)^2]}{E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]}-0$$
Then:
$$\frac{E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_i)^2]}{E[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]}=\frac{nE[\epsilon_1^2]}{nE[X_1^2]+n(n-1)E[X_1]^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{\tau^2+n\mu^2}$$

Am I right?

Comment: You seem to believe that $E\left(\frac{U}V\right)=\frac{E(U)}{E(V)}$ when $U$ and $V$ are independent. *This is very rarely so*, hence no, you are not right, not nearly. // By the way, what is your source for this? I am asking because the random variable whose variance you are asking for, is not even integrable...

Comment: @Did, this is Example 10.4 (b) in Casella's Inference (page 505). I am trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: ...And Casella and Berger should know better (but note the ambiguous formulation of the exercise, which *does not* ask for the variance). // "I am trying to figure out how to do it." Risking repetition, let me stress that my first comment explains why there is no way to do it. None. Nada. Zilch. Absolutely no way whatsoever.

Comment: I agree with @Did: the easiest way for me to see it was to consider the particular case of $n=1,\beta=0,\mu=0,\tau=\sigma$, in which case you are asked for the variance of the ratio of two independent Gaussians. However, it is known to be Cauchy distributed and hence has no finite moments.

Comment: I am very sorry, they asked for an approximate variance. Does that make a difference?

Comment: As I said before, mathematically speaking the exercise is absurd. Now, if I force myself to try to understand what C-B wants you to do, I arrive at the remark that, when $\mu\ne0$, the $X$-sum is approximately $n\mu$ and the $\epsilon$-sum is exactly $\sqrt{n}Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal with variance $\sigma^2$. From these facts, C-B might want you to deduce (**but this is wrong**) that the variance of the ratio would be approximately $E(nZ^2/(n\mu)^2)=\sigma^2/(n\mu^2)$. Who knows...

Comment: What is true however is that, if $\mu\ne0$, then $$U_n=\sqrt{n}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\epsilon_k}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k}$$ converges in distribution to some random variable $U$ such that $E(U)=0$ and $E(U^2)=\sigma^2/\mu^2$. And if $\mu=0$, then... (Up to you!)

Comment: @Did, I think this is exactly what they wanted us to do, thank you very much for a clear explanation.